# Moving domain user with linked mailbox

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

My organisation currently has two domains, one of which is slowly being fased out.
What I need to do is the following:
User "test" from DomainA needs to move to DomainB.
"test" has a linked mailbox to his disabled account on DomainB.

User "test" currently has the following accounts:

```
DomainA\test

DomainB\da-test(disabled)

LinkedMailbox "da-test"
```

I have already created a new user account on DomainB: "*DomainB\test*"

What is the best way to convert the linked mailbox "da-test" to a user mailbox "test", which should be connected to the new user "*DomainB\test*"?

This has to be done for all users from DomainA.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the linked mailbox "da-test", and then reconnect the disabled mailbox to the new user account on DomainB "DomainB\test". Details see:[Connect a disabled mailbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/disconnected-mailboxes/connect-disabled-mailboxes)